# How can I create a Node.js surrogate readable stream that will wrap another stream that's not available at the time the surrogate stream was created?

Tags: node.js, stream

I can make a simple HTTP request and get a stream back.

But what if I have to make an HTTP request, then poll to find out if the data is ready, then make another request to get the data?

I'd like to do that all in a single method that returns a stream so I can do:

```
multiStepMethod(options).pipe(wherever);
```

Instead of:

```
multiStepMethod(options, (err, stream) => {
    stream.pipe(wherever);
})
```

I need multiStepMethod to return a surrogate readable stream that will wait for some event and then wrap the (now available) stream and start sending it's data down the pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

'use strict';

const stream = require('stream');

// This is an example of a 'readable' stream that has to go through a multi-
// step process to finally get the actual readable stream. So we are
// asynchronously wrapping another readable stream.

// The key to simplicity here was to use a transform stream instead of a
// readable stream because it allows us to pipe the stream to ourselves.
class ReadableWrappingTransform extends stream.Transform {
  constructor() {
    super({
      objectMode: true,
      // Our _transform method doesn't really do anything and we don't want to
      // hog up any more additional memory than necessary.
      highWaterMark: 1
    });
    process.nextTick(() => {
      if (new Date().getTime() % 5 === 1) {

        // Here we simulate an error that happened somewhere in the multi-step
        // process to get the final stream. So we just emit 'error' and we're
        // done.
        this.emit('error', new Error('Could not get the stream.'));

        //Assuming based on the node docs that we should not emit
        // 'close' or 'end' on error. If we do emit 'end', it will trigger the
        // writable's 'finish' event, which is probably not desired. You either
        // want an 'error' OR a 'finish'.

        // NODE END EVENT DOCS
        // The 'end' event is emitted when there is no more data to be consumed
        // from the stream.

        // Note: The 'end' event will not be emitted unless the data is
        // completely consumed. This can be accomplished by switching the stream
        // into flowing mode, or by calling stream.read() repeatedly until all
        // data has been consumed.

        // this.emit('end');

        // NODE CLOSE EVENT DOCS
        // The 'close' event is emitted when the stream and any of its
        // underlying resources (a file descriptor, for example) have been
        // closed. The event indicates that no more events will be emitted, and
        // no further computation will occur.

        // Not all Readable streams will emit the 'close' event.

        // this.emit('close');
      } else {
        // We successfully got the stream we wanted after a long, hard, multi-
        // step process, so first we need to copy all our listeners over to it
        // -- NOT.

        // ['close', 'data', 'end', 'error'].forEach((eventName) => {
        //   this.listeners(eventName).forEach((l) => {
        //     readable.on(eventName, l);
        //   });
        // });

        // Turns out that .pipe propagates ALL listeners EXCEPT the 'error'
        // listener. What's up with that !?! If we copy any of the others  we
        // get double the events -- including double the data. So here we just
        // copy over the 'error' listener to make sure we get 'error' events.
        ['error'].forEach((eventName) => {
          this.listeners(eventName).forEach((l) => {
            readable.on(eventName, l);
          });
        });

        // Then just pipe the final readable to ourselves, and we are good.
        readable
          .pipe(this);
      }
    });
  }
  _transform(data, encoding, callback) {
    // Nothing special to do here just pass along the data.
    this.push(data);
    callback();
  }
}

// This is just a very unreliable test readable stream.
const readable = new stream.Readable({
  objectMode: true,
  read() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      if (new Date().getTime() % 13 === 1) {
        this.__err = new Error('Sorry, error reading data.');
        this.emit('error', this.__err);
        return;
      }
      this.push({
        Name: `Mikey ${i}`
      });
    }
    this.push(null);
  }
});

// Any old writable that we can pipe to.
const writable = new stream.Writable({
  objectMode: true,
  write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    console.log(chunk, encoding);
    callback();
  }
});

new ReadableWrappingTransform()
  // if your stream emits close you get close.
  .on('close', () => {
    console.error('CLOSE');
  })
  // if you push null you get end from read.
  .on('end', () => {
    console.error('END');
  })
  // error needs to be both places !?! seriously node?
  .on('error', (error) => {
    console.error('ERROR', error);
  })
  // Finish does no good here. It's a writable event.
  // .on('finish', () => {
  //   console.error('FINISH');
  // })
  .pipe(writable)
  // Close and End do no good here, they are readable events.
  // They are not propagated to the writable.
  //
  // // if your stream emits close you get close.
  // .on('close', () => {
  //   console.error('CLOSE');
  // })
  // // if you push null you get end from read.
  // .on('end', () => {
  //   console.error('END');
  // })
  // error needs to be both places !?! seriously node?
  .on('error', (error) => {
    console.error('ERROR', error);
  })
  // you should always get either finish or error or something was done
  // incorrectly.
  .on('finish', () => {
    console.error('FINISH');
  });
```